# magento 1.9.4.2 problem with search, server crashes

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I have problem witch search on my Magento
When I start a search for the word "hard drives", for some reason my server crashes.

But if I search by some other keywords, everything works well
what could it be? Does anyone have any options?
I have about 80 thousand products

I also noticed that some other SQL request in Magento 1.9.4.2

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2' WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(2267, 2268, 2269, 2270, 2271, 2272, 2274, 2275, 2276, 2277, 2278, 2279, 2280, 2282, 2283, 2284, 2285, 2286, 2287, 2288, 2289, 2290, 2291, 2292, 2293, 2294, 2295, 2296, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 2302, 2303, 2304, 2305, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2311, 2312, 2313, 2314, 2315, 2316, 2317, 2318, 2319, 2320, 2321, 2322, 2323, 2324, 2329, 2330, 2331, 2332, 2333, 2335, 2336, 2337, 2338, 2339, 2340, 2342, 2343, 2345, 2346, 2347, 2349, 2350, 2352, 2353, 2354, 2355, 2356, 2357, 2358, 2359, 2360, 2362, 2363, 2365, 2366, 2367, 2368, 2369, 2370, 2371, 2372, 2373, 2374, 2377, 2378, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2382, 2383, 2384, 2385, 2386, 2387, 2388, 2389, 2390, 2391, 2392, 2393, 2394, 2395, 2397, 2398, 2399, 2401, 2403, 2404, 2405, 2406, 2407, 2408, 2409, 2410, 2411, 2412, 2413, 2414, 2415, 2416, 2417, 2418, 2419, 2420, 2421, 2422, 2423, 2424, 2425, 2426, 2427, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2432, 2433, 2434, 2436, 2437, 2438, 2439, 2441, 2442, 2443, 2444, 2445, 2447, 2449, 2450, 2451, 2452, 2453, 2454, 2456, 2459, 2460, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2470, 2471, 2472, 2473, 2474, 2475, 2476, 2477, 2478, 2479, 2480, 2481, 2482, 2483, 2484, 2485, 2486, 2487, 2488, 2489, 2490, 2491, 2492, 2493, 2494, 2495, 2496, 2497, 2498, 2500, 2501, 2502, 2503, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2509, 2510, 2511, 2512, 2513, 2514, 2515, 2516, 2517, 2518, 2519, 2520, 2521, 2522, 2523, 2524, 2525, 2526, 2527, 2529, 2530, 2531, 2533, 2534, 2535, 2536, 2537, 2538, 2539, 2540, 2541, 2542, 2543, 2544))
```

Magento used other requests before if memory serves me right

Comment: With that many products the built in mysql search will be slow or crash. I recommend you invest some time in exploring alternatives.